# AttributeError: 'LocaleRegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_regex_dict' in django-cms

Tags: django, django-urls, django-cms, django-settings, django-errors

====When I run the project of `django-cms`, it shows me an `Attribute error like LocalRegexURLResolver i dont know how to solve this error please help me=====`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
  DeprecationWarning)

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 103, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 321, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 316, in resolve
    match = self.regex.search(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 432, in regex
    if language_code not in self._regex_dict:
**AttributeError: 'LocaleRegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_regex_dict'**
[28/Jun/2013 18:53:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 65272
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico/
```

=====How to solve this error =========

Comment: What did you use version of Django?

Comment: @Abbasov Alexander : django 1.5.1 and cms 2.4.2 please help i tried bt i couldn't solve help me please

Comment: @Aamir Adnan: django 1.5.1 and cms 2.4.2 please help i tried bt i couldn't solve help me please